# return redirect in aws API Gateway custom authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-api-gateway

I use an AWS API Gateway that has a custom authorizer (written in python) and instead of returning unauthorised when a user does not have a valid token, I want to redirect him to a different page. I want to deliver static html from a s3 bucket for authorised users. Unauthorised users should be redirected to the login page. The question is, how can I redirect the user?

I use cloudformation to define the environment. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just trying to do the same thing.  After reading the docs, it turns out you can't do this because it only supports a boolean yes/no to pass through to the gateway integration + the ability to pass context data.

Here is what you can return from a lambda authorizer.  Notice there is no HTTP related stuff you can configure.

```
{
  "isAuthorized": true/false,
  "context": {
    "exampleKey": "exampleValue"
  }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html